# Footer is not in place, body div is smaller than the content.

Tags: html, css, layout, footer

The problem is that my footer is not in place. However in `CSS` and `HTML` everything is set alright.

My body div is smaller than the content and I cannot fix this with height property. I spend several hours trying to resolve the issue, but I am still stuck.

http://www.sociofobic.ru/Socialphobia/paymentmethods.html

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. Read this ! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: And use this http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You are missing some closing div's (</div>) in your <form> and also missing the closing tag for the form table (</table>).  Fix those, and the footer goes to the correct position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that your layout is riddled with floats where you do not need them.  Consider removing some of your floats and that may begin to address some of the issues you're facing.  You may also want to think about putting your source HTML/CSS up somewhere we can edit/fork it.  Without actual source code on StackOverflow, it inhibits the ability to help you or others.